# Angular typescript async

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

This is likely a common/straightforward problem, but have had trouble finding a solution. My async call in typescript angular is not working. Once a dropdown is selected, I want to set the focus to a text box (in the dropdown). I'm setting focus using the elements id. The problem is 50% of the time it will work, but then it will also often say 'can't find element of undefined' (in the exact same scenarios), because the element has not been put into html until the dropdown is opened (I'm guessing about half the time the html will generate before the typescript executes and half not).

```
async delay(ms: number) {return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );}

async setFocus() { await delay(30000); log; getElement; focus(); }
```

The log prints immediately, so the await must not be working. Apologies for formatting. I've read multiple posts on this topic, and believe that this should be working, but it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Wrote this and wanted to post it even those I recently figured it out, but thought it was funny. corrected to this.delay, because apparently delay was referring to something else. New problem I may post soon: turns out it's delaying the entire opening of the box as well, so problem not solved.